# bluemix java application cannot be deployed anymore

Tags: jvm, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

We have had a java application that's been running on bluemix for more than a year that we update periodically (a few times a week). In the last few days however, even though the build is successful, we cannot launch it. The error is the following (we never saw this before):

```
  App/0 Error occurred during initialization of VMJul 10, 2017 12:13:14.002 PM
  App/0 Could not find agent library /home/vcap/app/.java-J-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/jvmkill-J-1.9.0_RELEASE in absolute path, with error: /home/vcap/app/.java-J-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/jvmkill-J-1.9.0_RELEASE: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The deploy cmd is

```
 cf push "${CF_APP}" -p target/universal/myapp-SNAPSHOT.zip -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git -k 2G
```

Comment: Are you able to deploy with an older version if the buildpack? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116320/cloudfoundry-use-an-older-buildpack-version

Comment: I tried with version `#e0915ee` (the one that I used when it last worked) and indeed it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are able to deploy using a previous version of the buildpack, this suggests that a recent change in the buildpack may be a reason for the latest buildpack breaking.

I was going to suggest opening a ticket on the [github repo](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/issues), but I see you have already done that :)