# Cloud Foundry : How use Java Buildpack specific version

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy  a Spring Boot App to Cloud Foundry. I have given the build pack in manifest.yml as below

```
---
applications:
- name: gl-bo-sample
  path: ./target/gl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
  buildpacks:
      - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git
```

Now I am trying to use it with a specific release, I tried changing the URL to

```
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#4.26
```

but getting below Error

```
Staging app and tracing logs...
   Cell 42004a5d-c593-4393-a123-f76cb8abe8b5 creating container for instance 43c3e913-e5a2-4251-b138-1309e117dc23
   Cell 42004a5d-c593-4393-a123-f76cb8abe8b5 successfully created container for instance 43c3e913-e5a2-4251-b138-1309e117dc23
   Downloading app package...
   Downloaded app package (26.2M)
   Failed to clone git repository at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git
   Exit status 1
   Cell 42004a5d-c593-4393-a123-f76cb8abe8b5 stopping instance 43c3e913-e5a2-4251-b138-1309e117dc23
   Cell 42004a5d-c593-4393-a123-f76cb8abe8b5 destroying container for instance 43c3e913-e5a2-4251-b138-1309e117dc23
   Cell 42004a5d-c593-4393-a123-f76cb8abe8b5 successfully destroyed container for instance 43c3e913-e5a2-4251-b138-1309e117dc23
Error staging application: Staging error: staging failed
FAILED
```

**Tried Adding #v4.26**
Getting a different Error -

```
Downloaded app package (26.2M)
   -----> Java Buildpack v4.26 | https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#e25d6bf
   [Buildpack]                      ERROR Finalize failed with exception #<RuntimeError: Open Jdk JRE error: No version resolvable for '1.8.0_232' in 1.7.0_06, 1.7.0_07, 1.7.0_08, 1.7.0_09, 1.7.0_10, 1.7.0_11, 1.7.0_12, 1.7.0_13, 1.7.0_14, 1.7.0_15, 1.7.0_17, 1.7.0_21, 1.7.0_25, 1.7.0_40, 1.7.0_45, 1.7.0_51, 1.7.0_55, 1.7.0_60, 1.7.0_65, 1.7.0_71, 1.7.0_75, 1.7.0_79, 1.8.0_00, 1.8.0_05, 1.8.0_11, 1.8.0_20, 1.8.0_25, 1.8.0_31, 1.8.0_40, 1.8.0_45, 1.8.0_51, 1.8.0_60, 1.8.0_65, 1.8.0_71, 1.8.0_73, 1.8.0_77, 1.8.0_91, 1.8.0_91-unlimited-crypto, 1.8.0_101, 1.8.0_111, 1.8.0_121, 1.8.0_131, 1.8.0_141, 1.8.0_144, 1.8.0_152, 1.8.0_161, 1.8.0_162, 1.8.0_172, 1.8.0_181, 1.8.0_191, 1.8.0_192, 1.8.0_201, 1.8.0_202, 1.8.0_212, 1.8.0_222, 1.8.0_RC1, 9.0.0_181, 9.0.1_11, 9.0.4_11, 10.0.0_46, 10.0.1_10, 10.0.2_13, 11.0.0_28, 11.0.1_13, 11.0.2_07, 11.0.2_09, 11.0.3_07, 11.0.4_11, 12.0.0_33, 12.0.1_12, 12.0.2_10>
   Open Jdk JRE error: No version resolvable for '1.8.0_232' in 1.7.0_06, 1.7.0_07, 1.7.0_08, 1.7.0_09, 1.7.0_10, 1.7.0_11, 1.7.0_12, 1.7.0_13, 1.7.0_14, 1.7.0_15, 1.7.0_17, 1.7.0_21, 1.7.0_25, 1.7.0_40, 1.7.0_45, 1.7.0_51, 1.7.0_55, 1.7.0_60, 1.7.0_65, 1.7.0_71, 1.7.0_75, 1.7.0_79, 1.8.0_00, 1.8.0_05, 1.8.0_11, 1.8.0_20, 1.8.0_25, 1.8.0_31, 1.8.0_40, 1.8.0_45, 1.8.0_51, 1.8.0_60, 1.8.0_65, 1.8.0_71, 1.8.0_73, 1.8.0_77, 1.8.0_91, 1.8.0_91-unlimited-crypto, 1.8.0_101, 1.8.0_111, 1.8.0_121, 1.8.0_131, 1.8.0_141, 1.8.0_144, 1.8.0_152, 1.8.0_161, 1.8.0_162, 1.8.0_172, 1.8.0_181, 1.8.0_191, 1.8.0_192, 1.8.0_201, 1.8.0_202, 1.8.0_212, 1.8.0_222, 1.8.0_RC1, 9.0.0_181, 9.0.1_11, 9.0.4_11, 10.0.0_46, 10.0.1_10, 10.0.2_13, 11.0.0_28, 11.0.1_13, 11.0.2_07, 11.0.2_09, 11.0.3_07, 11.0.4_11, 12.0.0_33, 12.0.1_12, 12.0.2_10
   Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run finalize script: exit status 1
   Exit status 223
   Cell 87d0c251-800c-46b8-b342-84120765ba39 stopping instance c9c63305-110d-4688-ae86-7df857a1debd
   Cell 87d0c251-800c-46b8-b342-84120765ba39 destroying container for instance c9c63305-110d-4688-ae86-7df857a1debd
   Cell 87d0c251-800c-46b8-b342-84120765ba39 successfully destroyed container for instance c9c63305-110d-4688-ae86-7df857a1debd
Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
FAILED
```

1. What I am doing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The anchor in the buildpack git URL should be prefixed with `v`, as in

```
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#v4.26
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26127753/1299533

Comment: Thanks, I tried but getting different Error, Edited in the question

Comment: This is the correct answer. The problem you're getting now is different. It's because you're requesting a version of Java not supported by the version of the buildpack that you've selected. This can happen if you're setting `JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE` and requesting a specific Java version. It can also happen if you were previously running a JBP version that had a version of Java and the new JBP version does not. I have seen cases where the cache retains the previous version. If that's the case, you need to `cf delete` your app and push again to clear the cache.

Comment: I tried deleting the app and pushing again. Still the issue is to resolved. Getting same error. Any idea what can be the cause or you need an additional details

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you alternate between offline and online buildpacks.

Please try this :

- Clean your blobstore cache `cf curl -X DELETE /v2/blobstores/buildpack_cache`
- Use offline buildpack:

  `cf create-buildpack my-custom-java-bp https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#v4.26 100 --enable`

And then refer to this buildpack in your manifest.

P.S. You can try both of these actions combined together, or just a first one.

Comment: Does this command ```cf curl -X DELETE /v2/blobstores/buildpack_cache``` affect other apps/builds in the SPACE, because there are other apps running there

Comment: I am using a custom build-pack now. Thanks for your answer.